# Rows to Column conversion Sql query SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a table name #Table1(See the attachment) I want following out put (See the attachment)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Raging Bull's answer is correct. Here is version using PIVOT

```
SELECT FormatType, [True], [False], [Blank], [True] + [False] + [Blank] AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT FormatType, Result
    FROM Table1
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Result)
    FOR Result IN ([True], [False], [Blank])
) AS PivotTable
```

It produces the exact same result.

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96a05/6)

Comment: +1 for another solution with pivot. BTW, took the liberty to add the example in fiddle, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT FormatType,
       ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN Result='True' THEN '1' END),0) AS [True],
       ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN Result='False' THEN '1' END),0) AS [False],
       ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN Result='Blank' THEN '1' END),0) AS [Blank],
       ISNULL(COUNT(1),0) AS [Total]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY FormatType
ORDER BY FormatType DESC
```

**Explanation:**

This query will select the `FormatType` along the count of each cases and the total. `ISNULL` is used for replacing `NULL` values with `0` (in case of `FALSE` in `ASP`).

Result:

```
FORMATTYPE  TRUE    FALSE   BLANK   TOTAL
PSP         1       2       1       4
ASP         1       0       2       3
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96a05/5).

Comment: Good one. Which query would someone use for such problems if `CASE` does not exist ? Is case present in all major RDBMS ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev: As far as I know, `CASE` is present and can be used in all major RDBMSs.